# Running Chrome as part of a build

Tags: testing, jenkins, functional-testing

I am trying to run Chrome on Windows as part of a set of automated testing tools whilst building a Chrome Extension.

The command below, loads about:blank in chrome, forces an extension to load, specifies a user directory and enables logging.

```
"c:\PATHTO\chrome.exe" --enable-logging --v=1 --load-extension=c:\JenkinsBuild --user-data-dir=c:\ChromeBuildTest about:blank
```

My intention is to then look through the log file for errors.

This works when I run it as manual process, but running through Jenkins the build just hangs.

I assume this is because `chrome.exe` never finishes and therefore never issues a return code.
Is there anyway to get this to work as I want?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using start command, start "c:\PATHTO\chrome.exe" .... This will open a new command prompt window, and the current job should not hang

Comment: This makes no difference the behavior. It still hangs.

Comment: That is because you may have specified the wrong user data directory. Usually it will be in C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

Comment: Its not. I am intentionally specifying a blank user directory. It works when I run it from the command line - creating the profile.